# Keep only second argument of print output in most pythonic way

Tags: python, pandas, list, printing

I have this code:

```
list_covid = []
for item in mainlist:
  lijstje.append(df['In het ziekenhuis opgenomen COVID-19 patiënten.csv_ogr_tmp_Zkh opname per 100.000'][df['ResponseId'] == item])

print(lijstje)
```

I get this output:

```
[125    **50.3**    Name: In het ziekenhuis opgenomen COVID-19 patiënten.csv_ogr_tmp_Zkh opname per 100.000, dtype: float64, 
 46     **51.2**    Name: In het ziekenhuis opgenomen COVID-19 patiënten.csv_ogr_tmp_Zkh opname per 100.000, dtype: float64, 
 126    **50.3**    Name: In het ziekenhuis opgenomen COVID-19 patiënten.csv_ogr_tmp_Zkh opname per 100.000, dtype: float64, 
 279    **NaN**     Name: In het ziekenhuis opgenomen COVID-19 patiënten.csv_ogr_tmp_Zkh opname per 100.000, dtype: float64
]
```

I want to store the bold (between **) numbers and store them in a list. Any ideas on how to do this in the most pythonic way

Comment: You could try with a regular expression.

Comment: @NomadMonad how would I do this?

Comment: You can checkout the `re` module in Python. This will help you extract information based on patterns in a string

Comment: You need to call the regex example posted by @Jack on each value that you append to the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real solution was to add .values to the end.

```
list_covid = []
for item in mainlist:
  lijstje.append(df['In het ziekenhuis opgenomen COVID-19 patiënten.csv_ogr_tmp_Zkh opname per 100.000'][df['ResponseId'] == item].values)

print(lijstje)
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @NomadMonad

```py
import re

lijstje= []
for item in mainlist:
  lijstje.append(df['In het ziekenhuis opgenomen COVID-19 patiënten.csv_ogr_tmp_Zkh opname per 100.000'][df['ResponseId'] == item])

print(lijstje)

r1 = re.findall(r"\*\*(.*?)\*\*",lijstje)
print(r1)
```

Comment: I get the following error if I try this: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: I assumed lijstje was what the print statement referred to, sorry. Just replace `lijstje` with whatever variable the print statement refers to. @TimVerlaan

Comment: I just cleared up the code. How would I adjust your script to get it working? I previously replaced lijstje with: df['In het ziekenhuis opgenomen COVID-19 patiënten.csv_ogr_tmp_Zkh opname per 100.000'][df['ResponseId'] == item] 

but that does not work

Comment: @TimVerlaan--it's highly recommended to place code updates in the posting section rather than the comments so others can follow.  Plus the posted section has better code display tools to help with viisualization.